# How to use Predicate with Generic Repository

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am following this tutorial 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990492/RESTful-Day-sharp-Enterprise-Level-Application?msg=5635950#xx5635950xx
He explains simple thing very well but as a beginner difficult for me to understand the implementation of the advanced function of Generic Repository

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetMany(Func<TEntity, bool> 
    where)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(where).ToList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generic method to get many record on the basis of a condition but 
    query able.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="where"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetManyQueryable(Func<TEntity, 
    bool> where)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(where).AsQueryable();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generic get method , fetches data for the entities on the basis of 
        condition.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="where"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public TEntity Get(Func<TEntity, Boolean> where)
    {
        return DbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault<TEntity>();
    }
```

I implement like this in my Service file

```
      public GEN_TransactionTypeSetup GetTransactionIdByTableName(string 
       tableName)
        {
        IEnumerable<GEN_TransactionTypeSetup> list = 
        _unitOfWorks.TransactionType_Repository.GetMany(p => 
         p.Master_TableName = tableName);
        return list.ToList();
       }
```

and i get the following error

- Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
- Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
  'System.Func' because some
  of the   return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to
  the delegate return   type
- Cannot implicitly convert type
  'System.Collections.Generic.List'
  to 'DataModels.GEN_TransactionTypeSetup'

Comment: Your return type doesn't match what your repository is returning as a result. An `IEnumerable<T>` can't be returned to a single type.

Comment: What is the solution of this ,I havent any idea how to resolve it

Comment: Now this line give error 
p.Master_TableName = tableName
Cannot implicity convert to bool ,as my where clause datafield is varchar datatype

Comment: Can be closed as off-topic because of simple typo `= tableName` => `== tableName`.

Comment: Yes I also get my silly mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be able to use the predicate in function of the `TEntity` type in your implementation.

Let's say your `TEntity` is `Person` (`GenericRepository<Person>`) and your `Person` has a property `Age`, which is an `int`.

You'll then be able to say:

```
IEnumerable<Person> result = repository.GetMany(p => p.Age > 18);
```

As you see, this (generic) method returns an `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, meaning you can apply (and chain) other Linq methods to your result.

Also note that the `ToList()` in

```
return DbSet.Where(where).ToList();
```

is superfluous and, in large resultsets, might create significant overhead because the method returns an `IEnumerable<TEntity>` and so already does a Linq `.Where()`.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response, I follow your steps my where clause have datatype varchar my code is 
public GEN_TransactionTypeSetup GetTransactionIdByTableName(string tableName)
        {
            IEnumerable<GEN_TransactionTypeSetup> list = _unitOfWorks.TransactionType_Repository.GetMany(p => p.Master_TableName = tableName);
            return list.ToList();
        }

Comment: it gives error 
Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool' 
Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<DataModels.GEN_TransactionTypeSetup,bool>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DataModels.GEN_TransactionTypeSetup>' to 'DataModels.GEN_TransactionTypeSetup'

Comment: Could you edit your question with this new information, so it's a little more structured?